# How to insert a certain value to rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, pandas-loc

I want to change a column from str to float. The column has now numbers with suffix 'M' or 'K' which I want to remove and keep only the number, and a string which I want to replace to 0.

1) In order to remove the chars M and K, I used it:

```
apps["Size"] = apps["Size"].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('M').rstrip('M'))
apps["Size"] = apps["Size"].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('K').rstrip('K'))
```

2) In order to change the value from "Varies with device" to 0, I tried using this:

```
mask = apps["Size"] == 'Varies with device'
apps.loc[mask, apps["Size"]] = '0'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the any easier way to change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove units by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and then convert values to numeric with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and `errors='coerce'` for another non numeric values to missing values, which are replaced by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
apps["Size"] = pd.to_numeric(apps["Size"].str.strip('KM'), errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```